# Google Places - get search text when searching return no results

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I don't post any code here, Google's tutorial is prettt straighforward. I used `AutocompleteSupportFragment` as described there: https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_1_embed_an_autocompletesupportfragment

But I also need to capture typed query text even in case when searching returns no items. Is that possible?

Comment: If this is absolutely necessary and you can't find any other way, you can create your own keyboard and listen and record keystrokes when users are typing to autocomplete fragment, I definitely don't recommend solving it like this though.

Comment: Nope, that's definitely wrong way